# Jekyll How to add content to multiple location

Tags: jekyll

How can I create multiple {{content}} in one layout file. Something like this...

_layout > default.html

```
<html>
<body>
  <H2>summary</H2>
  <p>
    {{content:summary}}
  </p>
  <H2>detail</H2>
  <p>
    {{content:detail}}
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

index.html

```
----
layout: default
----
content:summary
<b>show superhero</b>

content:detail
<b>Spiderman Batman Spiderman</b>
```

output

```
<html>
<body>
  <H2>summary</H2>
  <p>
    <b>show superhero</b>
  </p>
  <H2>detail</H2>
  <p>
    <b>Spiderman Batman Spiderman</b>
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jekyll only supports **one** content area. You can still use tricks to get a result like in your example.

Just put the summary into the YAML front-matter of your page:

#### index.html

```
----
layout: default
summary: "This is the summary"
----

This is the content
```

...and display it in your layout file like this:

#### _layouts/default.html

```
<html>
<body>
  <H2>summary</H2>
  <p>
    {{ page.summary }}
  </p>
  <H2>detail</H2>
  <p>
    {{ content }}
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

The output will look like this:

```
<html>
<body>
  <H2>summary</H2>
  <p>
    This is the summary
  </p>
  <H2>detail</H2>
  <p>
    This is the content
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi :-) I add "|" after variable for easy added HTML tag